# .map is not a function with react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to convert class component into a functional component , basically displaying all the nft's with map function using dummy data which i have declared. can anyone guide me through this . I've been getting this error .

> TypeError: nfts.map is not a function
> Responsive
> src/components/components/ColumnNew.js:256

```
import React, { Component,useState,useEffect } from "react";
import Clock from "./Clock";

 const Responsive = () => {

    let dummyData = [{
        deadline:"December, 30, 2021",
        authorLink: "ItemDetail",
        nftLink: "ItemDetail",
        bidLink: "ItemDetail",
        authorImg: "./img/author/author-1.jpg",
        previewImg: "./img/items/static-1.jpg",
        title: "Pinky Ocean",
        price: "0.08 ETH",
        bid: "1/20",
        likes: 50
    },
    {
        deadline:"",
        authorLink: "#",
        nftLink: "#",
        bidLink: "#",
        authorImg: "./img/author/author-10.jpg",
        previewImg: "./img/items/static-2.jpg",
        title: "Deep Sea Phantasy",
        price: "0.06 ETH",
        bid: "1/22",
        likes: 80
    },
    {
        deadline:"",
        authorLink: "#",
        nftLink: "#",
        bidLink: "#",
        authorImg: "./img/author/author-11.jpg",
        previewImg: "./img/items/static-3.jpg",
        title: "Rainbow Style",
        price: "0.05 ETH",
        bid: "1/11",
        likes: 97
    },
    {
        deadline:"January, 1, 2022",
        authorLink: "#",
        nftLink: "#",
        bidLink: "#",
        authorImg: "./img/author/author-12.jpg",
        previewImg: "./img/items/static-4.jpg",
        title: "Two Tigers",
        price: "0.08 ETH",
        bid: "1/20",
        likes: 50
    },
    {
        deadline:"",
        authorLink: "#",
        nftLink: "#",
        bidLink: "#",
        authorImg: "./img/author/author-9.jpg",
        previewImg: "./img/items/anim-4.webp",
        title: "The Truth",
        price: "0.08 ETH",
        bid: "1/20",
        likes: 50
    },
    {
        deadline:"January, 15, 2022",
        authorLink: "#",
        nftLink: "#",
        bidLink: "#",
        authorImg: "./img/author/author-2.jpg",
        previewImg: "./img/items/anim-2.webp",
        title: "Running Puppets",
        price: "0.08 ETH",
        bid: "1/20",
        likes: 50
    },
    {
        deadline:"",
        authorLink: "#",
        nftLink: "#",
        bidLink: "#",
        authorImg: "./img/author/author-3.jpg",
        previewImg: "./img/items/anim-1.webp",
        title: "USA Wordmation",
        price: "0.08 ETH",
        bid: "1/20",
        likes: 50
    },
    {
        deadline:"",
        authorLink: "#",
        nftLink: "#",
        bidLink: "#",
        authorImg: "./img/author/author-4.jpg",
        previewImg: "./img/items/anim-5.webp",
        title: "Loop Donut",
        price: "0.08 ETH",
        bid: "1/20",
        likes: 50
    },
    {
        deadline:"January, 3, 2022",
        authorLink: "#",
        nftLink: "#",
        bidLink: "#",
        authorImg: "./img/author/author-5.jpg",
        previewImg: "./img/items/anim-3.webp",
        title: "Lady Copter",
        price: "0.08 ETH",
        bid: "1/20",
        likes: 50
    },
    {
        deadline:"",
        authorLink: "#",
        nftLink: "#",
        bidLink: "#",
        authorImg: "./img/author/author-7.jpg",
        previewImg: "./img/items/static-5.jpg",
        title: "Purple Planet",
        price: "0.08 ETH",
        bid: "1/20",
        likes: 50
    },
    {
        deadline:"",
        authorLink: "#",
        nftLink: "#",
        bidLink: "#",
        authorImg: "./img/author/author-6.jpg",
        previewImg: "./img/items/anim-6.webp",
        title: "Oh Yeah!",
        price: "0.08 ETH",
        bid: "1/20",
        likes: 50
    },
    {
        deadline:"January, 10, 2022",
        authorLink: "#",
        nftLink: "#",
        bidLink: "#",
        authorImg: "./img/author/author-8.jpg",
        previewImg: "./img/items/anim-7.webp",
        title: "This is Our Story",
        price: "0.08 ETH",
        bid: "1/20",
        likes: 50
    },
    {
        deadline:"",
        authorLink: "#",
        nftLink: "#",
        bidLink: "#",
        authorImg: "./img/author/author-9.jpg",
        previewImg: "./img/items/static-6.jpg",
        title: "Pixel World",
        price: "0.08 ETH",
        bid: "1/20",
        likes: 50
    },
    {
        deadline:"January, 10, 2022",
        authorLink: "#",
        nftLink: "#",
        bidLink: "#",
        authorImg: "./img/author/author-12.jpg",
        previewImg: "./img/items/anim-8.webp",
        title: "I Believe I Can Fly",
        price: "0.08 ETH",
        bid: "1/20",
        likes: 50
    }]

    const [nfts, setnfts] = useState(0)
    const [height,setheight ] = useState(0)

    setnfts(dummyData.slice(0,8))

//   constructor(props) {
//     super(props);
//     this.state = {
//         nfts: this.dummyData.slice(0,8),
//         height: 0,
//     };
//     this.onImgLoad = this.onImgLoad.bind(this);
//     }

    const loadMore = () => {
        let nftState = nfts
        let start = nftState.length
        let end = nftState.length+4
        this.setState({
            nfts: [...nftState, ...(this.dummyData.slice(start, end))]
        });
        setnfts({...nftState,...(this.dummyData.slice(start, end)) })

    }

    function onImgLoad({target:img}) {
        let currentHeight = height;
        if(currentHeight < img.offsetHeight) {
            // this.setState({
            //     height: img.offsetHeight
            // })
            setheight(img.offsetHeight)
        }
    }

     
  return (
    <div className='row'>
        {nfts.map( (nft, index) => (
            <div key={index} className="d-item col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mb-4">
                <div className="nft__item m-0">
                    { nft.deadline &&
                        <div className="de_countdown">
                            <Clock deadline={nft.deadline} />
                        </div>
                    }
                    <div className="author_list_pp">
                        <span onClick={()=> window.open(nft.authorLink, "_self")}>                                    
                            <img className="lazy" src={nft.authorImg} alt=""/>
                            <i className="fa fa-check"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="nft__item_wrap" style={{height: `${height}px`}}>
                        <span>
                            <img onLoad={this.onImgLoad} src={nft.previewImg} className="lazy nft__item_preview" alt=""/>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="nft__item_info">
                        <span onClick={()=> window.open(nft.nftLink, "_self")}>
                            <h4>{nft.title}</h4>
                        </span>
                        <div className="nft__item_price">
                            {nft.price}<span>{nft.bid}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="nft__item_action">
                            <span onClick={()=> window.open(nft.bidLink, "_self")}>Place a bid</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="nft__item_like">
                            <i className="fa fa-heart"></i><span>{nft.likes}</span>
                        </div>                            
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>  
        ))}
        { nfts.length !== dummyData.length &&
            <div className='col-lg-12'>
                <div className="spacer-single"></div>
                <span onClick={() => loadMore()} className="btn-main lead m-auto">Load More</span>
            </div>
        }
    </div>              
    );
}

export default Responsive;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is occurring because you're initialising `nfts` as zero, and you can't `map` over an integer.

```
const [nfts, setnfts] = useState(0);
```

Set it to an empty array instead.

```
const [nfts, setnfts] = useState([]);
```

And you should move your `setnfts` call to inside [a `useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) otherwise you're going to get a cyclical rendering of that component, and a stack error. The empty dependency array ensures that the effect is only run once.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setnfts(dummyData);
}, []);
```

Comment: [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) a link for OP on using `useEffect` and `useState` in functional components, the idea is to completely remove the use of `setState` from Class Components. Further note, do not use `this` namespace in functional components.

Comment: I think the OP just forgot to comment that `this.setState` code out. @matabeitt

Comment: thanks for help andy , 
now i get this Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
i get this error

Comment: yeah i did comment that out now @andy

Answer (score 0):

React state variable `nfts` is initialized to `0` on first load.

```
const [nfts, setnfts] = useState(0);
```

`0` is not a valid array object. You should initialize state to an empty array, `[]` & load data in `useEffect`. You could also initialize data when declaring state with `useState` as well.

```
const [nfts, setnfts] = useState(dummyData.slice(0,8))
```

OR

```
const [nfts, setnfts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
 setnfts(dummyData.slice(0,8))
}, []);
```

As a defensive programming technique you can also do a few `null` checks -

```
{nfts && nfts.length > 0 && nfts.map ... }
```

Comment: Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
this is the error i face now @aseem

Comment: Could be due to changing state inside `useEffect` without any dependency array. You can should `useEffect` with an empty array. Please update the code if this does not solve's the problem.

Comment: ok now it worked !
just removed  setnfts(dummyData.slice(0,8))
thanks for the tips and help @aseem :)